# Comparing specific rows and whole rows in boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame ("Date", "A", "B"). I'm trying to use boxplot (by month) to analysis the data "A" for the row filtered by "B" and also for all the "A". I can only create two separate plots to do the boxplot for specific rows and for whole rows of data.

I tried two have 2 geom_boxplot under one ggplot(), but two boxplot just overlap with each other. Here is the code I used. Does anyone know how I can combime those two boxplot into one, so two boxplots will share same x axis, and each month in x axis will have two boxes.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = df %>% filter(B == 1), 
               aes(x = Month, y = A, group=Month, fill = "Chamber_no fire"), outlier.shape = T) +
  geom_boxplot(data = df, aes(x = Month, y = A, group=Month, fill="Chamber"), outlier.shape = T) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2,12,1), minor_breaks = F) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dotted")
ggsave("sate_meas_O3_NOx_5km_nofire.png", width = 6, height = 4, units = "in")
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). This will make it easy for others to help you by being able to test and verify solutions. These links may be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achieve your desired result is to

1. Bind the filtered dataset and the total dataset by row and add an identifier `id` for each dataset which could easily be done via `dplyr::bind_rows`.
2. Make a boxplot where you map `id` on the `fill` aesthetic and group by both `id` and `Month` using `interaction`
3. Set the legend labels via `scale_fill_discrete`

As you provided no data I make use of a random example data set:

```r
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  Month = sample(2:12, 100, rep = TRUE),
  A = rnorm(100),
  B = sample(1:2, 100, rep = TRUE)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d <- bind_rows(list(b1 = df %>% filter(B == 1),
                    all = df), .id = "id")

ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = Month, y = A, group=interaction(Month, id), fill = id)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = T, position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c(b1 = "Chamber_no fire", all = "Chamber")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2,12,1), minor_breaks = F) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dotted")
```

[image]